# How to spawn a docker container in a remote machine

Tags: python, docker

Is it possible, using the [docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), to launch a container in a remote machine?

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()

client.containers.run("bfirsh/reticulate-splines", detach=True)
# I'd like to run this container ^^^ in a machine that I have ssh access to.
```

Going through the documentation it seems like this type of management is out of scope for said SDK, so searching online I got hints that the [kubernetes client for Python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) could be of help, but don't know where to begin.

Comment: Do you have a k8s cluster or only docker cluster?

Comment: @RadekW I only have a docker cluster, but if using k8s is straightforward for this case I'd go for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, simply do this:

```py
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url=your_remote_docker_url)
```

Here's the document I found related to this:

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#client-reference

---

If you only have SSH access to it, there is an `use_ssh_client` option

Comment: @LorahAttkins I didn't down-voted this question...

Answer (score 9):

It's not clearly documented by [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), but you can use [SSH to connect to Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/) by specifying host with `ssh://[user]@[host]` format, for example:

```py
import docker

# Create a client connecting to Docker daemon via SSH
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url="ssh://username@your_host")
```

It's also possible to set environment variable `DOCKER_HOST=ssh://username@your_host` and use the example your provided which use current environment to create client, for example:

```py
import docker
import os

os.environ["DOCKER_HOST"] = "ssh://username@your_host"
# Or use `export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://username@your_host` before running Python

client = docker.from_env()
```

---

Note: as specified in the question, this is considering you have SSH access to target host. You can test with

```sh
ssh username@your_host
```

Comment: Awarding the bonus here cause you went the extra mile with your explanation. I accepted the other answer since they posted first and it's the same solution essentially.

Answer (score 0):

As has been previously answered:

```
import docker

client = docker.DockerClient(base_url="ssh://user@host_name_or_ip")
```

is the correct code, however, I still received an error:

`docker.errors.DockerException: Install paramiko package to enable ssh:// support`

As the error states, it was resolved by installing the [Parmiko package](https://www.paramiko.org/).

I also already had [pubkey authentication](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#Copying_the_public_key_to_the_remote_server) configured in my ssh config.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a k8s cluster, you do not need the Python sdk. You only need the cmd line tool [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/).

Once you have it installed, you can create a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) that will deploy your image.