# dockerpy sdk unable to connect to remote server

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I'm currently trying to use the dockerpy sdk to connect to my remote ubuntu server so i can manage my docker containers via python.

I am getting a few issues when attempting to do this.

```py
docker.APIClient(base_url="ssh://user@ip")
```

When doing the following I am getting the error:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: private key file is encrypted
```

I can resolve this issue by adding the kwarg: `use_ssh_client`, but then i am forced to input a password, which limits the potential for automation.

```py
docker.APIClient(base_url="ssh://user:@ip", use_ssh_client=True)
```

When using the above code, I have also tried to enter my ssh key password into the base_url such as:

```
docker.APIClient(base_url="ssh://user:pass@ip", use_ssh_client=True)
```

However, this then greets me with the following error:

```
docker.errors.DockerException: Invalid bind address format: ssh://root:pass@ip
```

I have run out of ideas and am confused as to how I am supposed to get around this?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem. Your Problem is, that you Key is encrypted. The Docker Clients doesn't have a Passphrase option by default. I wrote some Code based on [this](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2416) Post. It works for me :)

```
import os
from docker import APIClient
from docker.transport import SSHHTTPAdapter

class MySSHHTTPAdapter(SSHHTTPAdapter):
    def _connect(self):
        if self.ssh_client:
            self.ssh_params["key_filename"] = os.environ.get("SSH_KEY_FILENAME")
            self.ssh_params["passphrase"] = os.environ.get("SSH_PASSPHRASE")
            self.ssh_client.connect(**self.ssh_params)


client = APIClient('ssh://ip:22', use_ssh_client=True, version='1.41')
ssh_adapter = MySSHHTTPAdapter('ssh://user@ip:22')
client.mount('http+docker://ssh', ssh_adapter)
print(client.version())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make a connection as Mr. Piere [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71616682/7016425). Even with that question about *docker.client.DockerClient* which uses *docker.api.client.APIClient* under the hood.

You are trying to establish a connection using **Password Authentication** that's why you asked to prompt a password.
I guess you need to configure the **Key-Based SSH Login** as said in [docker's docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#ssh-tips)

Steps to fix:

1. [configure](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) SSH Login on a remote server and fill `~/.ssh/config` on your local machine
2. connect from the local terminal using the ssh command to ensure a connection is established *without asking password* `ssh user@ip`
3. connect using library `client = docker. APIClient(base_url="ssh://user@ip", use_ssh_client=True)`

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. While this could be useful, its not quite what I am looking for. I have to be able to dynamically manage my servers, so manually having to login and then use the ssh client is not really a valid option.

Comment: @jaalkamza maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't mrAndrew's solution configure your ssh config folder with keys, so that you don't have to manually login via ssh anymore, from the machine where you do the steps he suggested?